# PdfNet SDK for .Net Core WebApi from pdftron

Tags: pdftron

I am trying to linearize a pdf document for displaying in PDFTron WebViwer.To achive this i am using client side angular and backed .Net core WebApi.

I need to linearize pdf document in .NetCore Web api using pdftron pdfnet sdk, but the problem is i ma not getting any supported dll for .NetCore 2.2 frame work.

Please let me know the correct sdk which support my api.

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know the correct sdk which support my api.

Below are the .NET Core SDK builds you are looking for.

[Windows 32bit](https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/PDFNetC.zip)

[Windows 64bit](https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/PDFNetC64.zip)

[Linux 32bit](https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/PDFNetC.tar.gz)

[Linux 64bit](https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/PDFNetC64.tar.gz)

Once you downloaded the SDK, run one of the .NET Core samples by extracting the package, going to a sample, such as `Samples/AddImageTest/CS` and then `dotnet run`

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/dotnetcore/get-started/integration/windows